# How can I return json data from my php local server using the HTTPrequests library in python?

Tags: php, python, json, python-2.7

My Python script:

```
import requests
import json
location = '127.0.0.1'
port = 8000

# Setup the REST API URL string
apiString = 'http://' + location + ':' + str(port) + '/edsa-Python/Matrix_mult_dynamic/run_python.php'
print apiString

#Make the REST API Request
resp = requests.get(apiString)
print resp.text
# print resp.encoding

# Get the JSON that is returned
if resp.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    the_json = resp.json()
    #print the_json
```

Error: I get an error saying that No JSON object could be decoded.
Below is the error that I get when I run the python script in the command prompt:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/edsa-Python/Matrix_mult_dynamic/run_python.php

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client_python.py", line 25, in <module>
    the_json = resp.json()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg\requests\models.py", line 841, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: Can you please add `print(resp.text)` to the code adter the `get()` call and add the output to your question?

Comment: I just added the print resp.text line after the resp = requests.get(apiString). This 'print resp.text' does not seem to print anything, it is just a blank. @Klaus

Comment: Then, you are receiving an empty response from the server, which off cause is not valid JSON.

Comment: My php script is getting content from a JSON file. I am attempting to get that JSON content to my python script. How can I return the JSON data to my python script? Any suggestions, please. @Klaus

Comment: If you just want to get the JSON file, serve it with any webserver of your choice statically without PHP.

Comment: I am using EasyPHP server. It was already setup when I installed it. I don't understand what you mean by "statically without PHP"? Can you explain please?

Comment: I was able to solve my problem. My URL was incorrect. Instead of using run_python.php, I changed it to my file with the .json extension. It works now.